# Performance Issue while operating among two columns of a dataframe

Tags: r, performance, dataframe, lapply

Given a dataframe with two columns:

- length (length of elements)
- findLengthOf (This is a string of values) The index of the elements for which the length is needed

So one has to find all the length of all indexes in the second column and put the result in a third column. 
Please see above example, where we search for the lenght of 1637 and obtain 1835:

```
> df$length[1637]
[1] 1835


head(df)
  length findLengthOf
1   6434 1637,386....
2   4272 4322,414....
3   7338 2052,639....
4   4932 190,1567....
5   2397 8963,844....
6   4405 103,4346....

    head(df)
  length findLengthOf           result
1   6434 1637,386.... 1835, 2404, 4689
2   4272 4322,414.... 1184, 2721, 7215
3   7338 2052,639.... 5253, 2998, 6153
4   4932 190,1567.... 2931, 6496, 7784
5   2397 8963,844.... 3796, 3488, 6555
6   4405 103,4346.... 1662, 5481, 1244

set.seed(123)
df <- data.frame(length = sample(1e4),
                 findLengthOf = I(replicate(1e4, paste(sample(1:10000,1),sample(1:10000,1),sample(1:10000,1),sep=","), simplify = FALSE)))

df$result=lapply(lapply(df$findLengthOf,strsplit,split=","), function(x){df[x[[1]],"length"]})
```

Code works, but it takes to long. How can I improve the speed?
Also why does

```
head(lapply(df$findLengthOf,strsplit,split=","))
```

always return this weird list of lists with:

```
[[1]]
[[1]][[1]]
[1] "7744" "1346" "4626"
```

Is there a way to avoid these double brackets?
Any response is greatly appreciated!

Suggestion from David (set fixed=T):

```
> ptm <- proc.time()
> df$result=lapply(lapply(df$findLengthOf,strsplit,split=",",fixed=T), function(x){df[x[[1]],"length"]})
> proc.time() - ptm
   user  system elapsed 
 17.220   0.000  17.147 
> ptm <- proc.time()
> df$result=lapply(lapply(df$findLengthOf,strsplit,split=","), function(x){df[x[[1]],"length"]})
> proc.time() - ptm
   user  system elapsed 
 17.260   0.000  17.142
```

Comment: Not clear `lenght of 1637 and obtain 1835` ?

Comment: Hi zx8754, alright. That means df$length[1637] results in 1835. Ill update my post.

Comment: By simply adding `fixed = TRUE` to the `strsplit` call you could make it run faster by ~X10 times. Also. both `strsplit` and `lapply` return a list, hence list of lists. I'm also wondering how this question relates to your previous one, when you ignored performance comparison and alternative suggestions such as not concatenate to a string in the first place and etc.

Comment: Hi David, thanks for the input! Give me a sec to test that.

Comment: David, in my previous question performance wasnt an issue. I was glad it worked at all. Now I need operations like that more often and it becomes an issue. Thanks for the hint with the list of lists, I am still a beginner when it comes to R coding. The fixed=T did not have the desired effect.

Comment: Ok, I'll post a fully vectorized answer which can get memory expensive, but I have not time to test for performance. Tell me if it any better

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a fully vectotorized solution but possibly memory expensive. I haven't tested for performance

```
library(data.table)
res <- matrix(df$length[unlist(setDT(df)[, 
              tstrsplit(findLengthOf, ",", fixed = TRUE, type.convert = TRUE)])],
              nrow = nrow(df))
df$result <- as.list(as.data.frame(t(res)))
```

Comment: I appreciate the effort, going to test performance later cause it's lunch time here in Germany. I'll post the results afterwards.

Comment: Amazing! It takes:    user  system elapsed 
                                 0.04    0.00    0.04  Where can I learn more about vetorizing my code? Do you have any good tutorials?

Comment: Vectorizing code in R is a mindset. It comes with experience. I've tried to provide some intro [here](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/r/3327/r-code-vectorization-best-practices#t=201608021213337797116). This is also a good intro http://www.noamross.net/blog/2014/4/16/vectorization-in-r--why.html